# Question on deserializing Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi how do I deserialize json objects of the type?

```
 {"photo":{"id":5, "url":"http://pics.com/pic1.jpg"}};
```

Because normally I would create a Class:

```
public class Photo{
  private int id;
  private String url;

  public Photo(){
   }    
}
```

And then just run it using:

```
  GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
  Gson gson = gsonb.create();      
  Photo photo = gson.fromJson(response, Photo.class);
```

But that just fills everything with nulls.
It would work if I the Json was only

```
 {"id":5, "url":"http://pics.com/pic1.jpg"}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another class that has the Photo class as property

```
public class PhotoRoot {

  private Photo photo;

  public void setPhoto(Photo val) {
    photo = val;
  }

  public Photo getPhoto() {
    return photo;
  }

}
```

Then Parse it like

```
GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonb.create();      
PhotoRoot photoRoot = gson.fromJson(response, PhotoRoot.class);

Photo yourPhoto = photoRoot.getPhoto();
```

Regards

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but it seems to me that Gson has (or should have, anyway) a way to map how a json field is mapped to an object...

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure is not valid. You need to change it to

```
 {"id":5, "url":"http://pics.com/pic1.jpg"}
```

to match your Photo class.

The reason why `{"photo":{"id":5, "url":"http://pics.com/pic1.jpg"}}` doesn't work is that GSON looks for a property called `photo` within your Photo class which doesn't exist.

Comment: It's often the case where we don't have access to change the API. Furthermore, the convention seems to be to wrap all objects in a named JSON object. I'd rather our libraries adhere to these conventions than the other way around.